# Escaping numbers and special chars in python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have form and I want that its fields will not match any numbers and any special chars.

Now,

I have like this

```
name = forms.RegexField(regex = r'[^0-9]+$')
```

It just escapes numbers, now.

How to set a regex pattern for escaping numbers and special chars. Any advice?

Comment: What special characters do you want to check?

Comment: are alphanumerics allowed? i mean, is "abc123" allowed?

Comment: It would help if you specify want to want to allow and what you want to disallow as *special characters* is too vague at the moment.

Comment: All I want is typing alphabetic char. Example: 'armağan' or 'julia' or 'computer engineer' not 'arm123' or not '#45hgy' or not '3d,A' just alphabetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that words containing alphabets and numbers both are allowed, this regex could do the work

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

this would check that the input field must contain atleast one character, and would only allow alphabets, or a combination of alphabets and numbers. No special characters are allowed. `abc` `12abc` `abc12` are valid, but `123` `ab@/` are invalid.

What I did is, I reversed the approach. Instead of restricting special characters, i allowed only alphabets and the above mentioned combination. This automatically restricted special characters.

If escaping numbers is the requirement, this regex could be used:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

this would only allow alphabets, and would restrict all numbers and all special characters.

Comment: `escaping numbers and special chars` is the requirement.

Comment: i updated my answer and added the regex for not allowing numbers and special characters.

Comment: It looks well it do not allow numbers and special chars but it allow the pattern that starting with alphabet char later special chars or numbers in the tail. Like this 'arm23' and 'arm**'. But I don't want them.

Comment: i believe the second regex in my answer would satify your need completely. It would only allow alphabets and nothing else.

Comment: still if you are facing any problem, do let me know.

Comment: ohh yeah. actually `^` shows start of the string, and `$` represents the end. So adding them would definitely solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah I forget ^  :) and '12ar' was alowed. Now, I fixed. But I have a problem. I can't write 'arm arm' space is not allowed :(

Comment: actually space is one of the special characters. if you want special characters to be allowed, use this regex: `[a-zA-Z\s]+`

Answer (score 0):

Here a table to see all regexp simbols:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

For your problem, if I understand what you want it should be... r'[a-zA-Z]+$'

Dont know, but look at the table in the link, its very usefull.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I fixed the missing but It looks usefull for general knowhow about regex.

Comment: The link is for RegExp in Javascript. Granted that they have similarities, but Python has other features that Javascript regex doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to match only letters.

To be unicode compatible, use [properties](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) :

```
\p{L}+
```

This will match one or more letter in any language.

Comment: I encountered this pattern. But I don't understand how to use it in django form.

Comment: @Armagan: I don't know django, but just use it as a usual regex. It's the same than ascii letter `[a-zA-Z]+` with all languages letters.

Comment: @M42: IIRC, django should be using re module in python, which doesn't support character properties.